# Fseek adds NUL = \u0 characters to the output file

Tags: php, encoding, fopen, fwrite, fseek

Iam creating a simple PHP application, where is a csv file upload then an .stm(its a simple text file) file download. The records must be write at given byte position. For example: 1st record position 1, length 2, 2nd record, etc.[Records](https://snag.gy/PpBFIC.jpg)

So Im trying to use fwrite, fseek to get to given position, for example I dont need 2 record to be filled, so I jump to position 11 but there are NUL characters in the file.

Code:

```
$input = $sFileName;
//a nevbol kiszedni a datumot, majd EEEEHHNN verziora konvertalni
$get_date_from_name = str_replace(".","",substr($sFileName,0,10));
$output = $get_date_from_name . '_mpl_tensoft_import.stm';

$_SESSION['file_name'] = $output;

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) {

$oh = fopen($output, 'w+b');

//Create first line of the file 11 record type
fwrite($oh,"11");
fseek($oh, 11);
fwrite($oh,"120967120159857100100007");

/*while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih,0,";"))) {
    // this is where you build your new row
    //Interne cislo, Dodavatel, Dodavacie c.faktury Celk.suma, Dátum prijatia, Dátum splat. = Datum uhrady, Predmet 
    $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[12], $data[13],  $data[36] );
    fputcsv($oh, $outputData);
}*/

fclose($ih);
fclose($oh);

unlink($input);
}
```

Result is:

```
11NULNULNULNULNULNULNULNULNUL120967120159857100100007
```

Visual Studio Code gives an error that the file is binary or to large or uses an unsupported encoding.

Notepad++ adds the NUL characters.

Should I just use a whitespace character? 1 whitespace character equals 1 byte? The file should be in CP852 encoding

Thanks for the help and pointing in to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your `seek()` offset seems to be "out of range".

[Documentation](https://secure.php.net/fseekhttps://secure.php.net/fseek) said :

> In general, it is allowed to seek past the end-of-file; if data is then written, reads in any unwritten region between the end-of-file and the sought position **will yield bytes with value 0**.

**EDIT :**

If you want to put the second number at offset 13, using spaces, you could do something like this :

```
$ban_pos = 13 ;
$num = "11" ;
$pos = $ban_pos - strlen($num) ;
$ban = "120967120159857100100007" ;

$oh = fopen($output, 'w+');
fwrite($oh, $num);
fwrite($oh, str_repeat(' ', $pos));
fwrite($oh, $ban);
fclose($oh);
```

The file will contains :

> `11           120967120159857100100007`

Comment: Hi, thanks. So I need to fclose and fopen the file all the time if I want to change the byte position and use fwrite? Thanks :)

Comment: @beamkiller Maybe I don't understand. What do you want to have between offset 2 and 13?

Comment: nothing should be there. So first record is 11, second is empty, third is a bank account number from byte position 11 24byte positions = 24 characters.

Comment: @beamkiller Maybe you'll have to change offsets, but I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I had in mind this solution too but I was not sure that 1 whitespace character gives me exactly 1 byte of data :) I'm going to try it with this method.

Comment: @beamkiller Don't forget to close this question if it works ! Thanks.